# Convert large number with comma/decimal to Double

Tags: java

My server is returning a string like 2,100.00.

I get a NumberFormatException when I try to convert this String into a double.

```
Double.valueOf("2,100.00");
```

Do I have to remove the decimal/comma, convert, and add the decimal back in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set a custom separator in a decimal format

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
Number number = df.parse(str);
```

Then you can use the `number`. To convert it to double you can do `number.doubleValue()`

Comment: Thanks so much, saved me some time hunting out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to remove the comma. This solution would be more simple:

```
String str = "2,100.00";
Double.valueOf(str.replaceAll(",", ""));
```